# Mandrill returns reject_reason: 'invalid-sender'

Tags: node.js, smtp, mandrill

I have a node.js application and I want to use Mandrill to send transactional emails. However, when I send, I get "reject_reason: 'invalid-sender'". Here's some logging to show what's happening:

```
MandrillMail::send sent 
 { 
  from: 'counselor@nosend.com',
  to: [ { type: 'to', email: 'toddrun@nosend.com' } ],
  text: 'Sample Message',
  html: '<p>Sample Message</p>',
  subject: 'Regarding your account with Zev J' 
 }
and got back 
 [ { 
   email: 'toddrun@nosend.com',
   status: 'rejected',
   _id: '0ef9980ab50d448cb8bc1fcec2d614fc',
   reject_reason: 'invalid-sender' 
 } ]
```

Note that in the actual log file, the "nosend" values are the real domains, and all the email addresses are real inboxes that I can send test messages to via Gmail.

So, what's causing the 'invalid-sender'? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mandrill "reject\_reason": "invalid-sender"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604551/mandrill-reject-reason-invalid-sender)

Answer (score 6):

Let this be a lesson that no matter how many times you look at code you've written, typos can be really really hard to find. Note that I have "from" instead of "from_email" . . . duh!

Comment: I bet if someone looked over your shoulder while you had the code up on screen, they would have picked it up instantly - even if you couldn't see it after staring at it for ages. I think they call it "code blindness". Happens to all of us at some point!

Comment: Simon, I agree! There's something to be said for pair programming . . . when it's available. It would have saved me a ton of time and frustration here.

Comment: Thanks. 
If anyone needs more information, check the below docs.
https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html